# creating a recurrence relation for a given interval

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

How can I come up with a recurrence relation such that

> $T(1)=1$
>
> $n^2\log_2n\le T(n) \le 3n^2\log_2 n+1,\;\forall n\ge 1$

Comment: Welcome to MSE ^_^ What have you tried? Do you have any ideas of your own? Once we know where you're struggling, we can help you better.

Comment: I have tried T(n) = 4 T(ceil(n/2)) + n^2 -n but I guess I cannot prove it with induction